# AngularJs Jquery ng-repeat accordion is not working

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui-accordion

I am trying to use ng-repeat with jquery accordion just following some how to but it does not work at all:

I tried to use change the CDN order but it does not work as well...

(html)

```
<html>
<head>

<script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"   integrity="sha256-slogkvB1K3VOkzAI8QITxV3VzpOnkeNVsKvtkYLMjfk="   

crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.js"> </script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/angular.bootstrap/2.1.2/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="angular.js"></script>

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<title>Teste</title>
</head>

<body>
<div ng-app="ui.bootstrap.module" >
  <div ng-controller="ui.bootstrap.ctrl">


    <accordion close-others="true">

      <accordion-group ng-repeat="x in numOfMaps" 
                       heading="{{x.header}}" 
                       is-open="status.isFirstOpen" 
                       is-disabled="status.isFirstDisabled">
        {{x.text}}
      </accordion-group>

    </accordion>

  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

(js)

```
var app = angular.module('ui.bootstrap.module', ['ui.bootstrap']);
app.controller('ui.bootstrap.ctrl', function ($scope) {

  $scope.numOfMaps = [ 
    {count: 1, text: "Text 1", header: "Header 1"},
    {count: 2, text: "Text 3", header: "Header 2"},
    {count: 2, text: "Text 3", header: "Header 3"}
  ];

});
```

(browser answer)

Text 1 Text 3 Text 3

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7fLyq.png)

Comment: Is there any error in console?

Comment: Do you get any errors in console?

Comment: if you are already using angular ui bootstrap, can I ask why are you using jquery accordion? Why dont you use https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/accordion that doesnt depend on jquery at all...

Comment: No errors in console, the console is blank...

Comment: This is the accordion I am using, i just made a mistake...

Comment: I just edit with the browser/console screeshot...

Comment: @GustavoGabriel Just copied and paste the code in the URL you mentioned and it is working properly...

Answer (score 0):

Your tags are not correct if you are using the angular-ui-bootstrap accordion. This part of your markup should look like this:

```
<uib-accordion close-others="true">

  <div uib-accordion-group ng-repeat="x in numOfMaps" 
                   heading="{{x.header}}" 
                   is-open="status.isFirstOpen" 
                   is-disabled="status.isFirstDisabled">
    {{x.text}}
  </div>

</uib-accordion>
```

More info here:
https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/wiki/Migration-guide-for-prefixes